# In Notes designer v12 xpages error "Access restriction: Java Problem"

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I installed Lotus Designer v12 and when I try to open a database with HCL Domino designer I get the next error: "Access restriction: The constructor 'UISelect2PickerCombo()' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\HCL\Notes\Data\workspace\applications\eclipse\plugins\org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap_1.0.0.201407020945.jar')  CcCabecera.java /dddbbbb.nsf/Local/xsp  line 251    Java Problem".

[image]

It works fine in Domino designer v9.

I tried to change the JDK Compiler Compliance level to 1.5 , add in Target Platform, the  folder but always I get the same error

Any help??

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore the error. Go to Domino Designer preferences and change the error to 'ignore'. It's one of the 'api' problems.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try edit access rules for library.

1. Goto 'Project properties' of database, then 'Java Build Path', then 'Libraries' tab.
2. In 'Plug-in Dependencies' branch try to find `org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap` item
3. Expand item and select 'Access rules' item, then on right use button 'Edit...'
4. Scroll down and select item `**/*`, then use 'Edit...' button
5. Set 'Resolution' to value 'Accessible' and confirm
6. Clean and rebuild